# Trouble calling a variable from another .php file

Tags: php, variables, require

Similar questions have been asked before, but after following several working examples closely I cannot get this to work for me.

I am trying to access the variable `$nameValues` that was declared in insert-name.php

insert-name.php is the first script that runs:

```
 error_reporting(-1);
$nameValues  = "'".implode("', '", array_values($nameArray))."'";
print_r($nameValues); // returns the expected variable
```

and insert-answer.php is the second script to run:

```
 error_reporting(-1);
require "insert-name.php";
if (isset($nameValues)) {
   print_r("nameValues variable:" . $nameValues);
} else {
   echo "variable nameValues does not exist";
}
//returns nameValues variable:'' indicating that $nameValues exists but is empty
```

Both .php files are stored in the same folder on my webserver. I've tried using both `require` and `include` statements. I successfully use a `require` statement to connect to my database in both scripts, not sure why it is not working for `insert-name.php`.

### Edit:

No errors are reported.
If statement returns "nameValues variable:'' " indicates that `$nameValues` variable exists but is empty.

I also tried replacing `require "insert-name.php";` with `require __DIR__."/insert-name.php";` which returned "variable nameValues does not exist" from the if statement.

Because neither gave a fatal error both`require` statements successfully accessed the insert-name.php file, but I don't know why one method thinks `$nameValues` doesn't exist and the other thinks `$nameValues` is empty.

Comment: try `require __DIR__."/insert-name.php";`

Comment: Also, please add `error_reporting(-1);` as early as possible in your script and post any errors that pop up.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I forgot to include `error_reporting` here. No errors are shown.

Comment: Ok now replace print_r with var_dump let's make sure we are getting a empty string and not FALSE, 0, or NULL

Comment: Also, if adding `__DIR__` changes the output, it means that is a part of the problem. This is because of how include paths work in PHP. Now I want you to make sure you are always using `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem accessing the variables from another file like you have provided they are in the same scope (one is not inside a function etc.).  In your case it looks like it is just a case of how you are calling  `print_r()`

When you do `print_r('nameValues variable:" . $nameValues)` you are converting `$nameValues` into a string.

Try something like this to dump your `$nameValues`:

```
error_reporting(-1);
require "insert-name.php";
if (isset($nameValues)) {
    echo "nameValues variable: ";
    print_r($nameValues);
} else {
    echo "variable nameValues does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said:

> `returns nameValues variable:''`

There was one detail I overlooked, the quotation marks at the end. When you echo a string in PHP it only prints the content (there are no quotations printed, unless they are in the string).

Effectively this all just means that `$nameArray` is empty, so check the script that generates this. Also, because of how `implode()` works, `array_values()` is completely redundant here.

As simple way to test this is `echo count($nameArray);`. If the output is "0" the array is empty.